# Connecting a COM Event Source via Interop

Tags: c#, com-interop

I am trying to expose a COM Event Source from C#. 
I have the following event interface that is imported from a TLB:

```
[Guid("AAAABBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEFFFFAAAA")]
[InterfaceType(2)]
[TypeLibType(4096)]
public interface _IFooEvents
{
   [DispId(20)]
   void FooEvent(int Value);
   // Remainder of elements omitted for brevity
}
```

I'm attempting to implement this event interface as a source on a `ComVisible` object defined in my application:

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBBAAAAFFFF")]
[ComSourceInterfaces("_IFooEvents")]
class FooConcrete : IFoo
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void FooEvent(int Value);
    // Remainder of delegates omitted for brevity.

    public event FooEvent TheFooEvent;

 }
```

This source is then used by a sink implemented in C++ using ATL.

```
HRESULT AdviseResult = _IDispEvent::DispEventAdvise(pUnk, IID__IFooEvents);
```

The `HRESULT` returned is `0x80131522: Could not find or load a type`.

Comment: It is a simple TypeLoadException.  Gets to be hard to see without a managed debugger, so enable it by setting the Debugger Type to Mixed.  Not being able to find an assembly is very, very common in a COM scenario.  The CLR has no shot at finding dependent assemblies, unless you use the GAC.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to diagnose.  Prefer a monolithic assembly, also ensure you have the Embed Interop Types property set to True so you don't have a dependency on the interop library that is needed to define the event interface.

Comment: @HansPassant Modifying the library to be embedded solved the problem. Go ahead and post that as an answer if you would like, I'll accept it.